# Divisible Function Scheme

Tags: scheme, predicate

I'm trying to write a function that determines if a number is divisible by 2 or 3. From what i've read online there is already a Scheme predicate divisible? but it is not working for me. I've tried writing one myself, but I don't know how to write a predicate function. Is there any help I can get?
Thanks!

Comment: A predicate function is just any function that returns `#t` or `#f`

Comment: And AFAIK there isn't a built-in predicate for this, you'll have to implement it

Answer (score 2):

The `divisible?` predicate can be expressed in terms of the `remainder` procedure, remember: a number `n` is divisible by `x` if the remainder of dividing `n` by `x` is zero.

```
(define (divisible? n x)
  (zero? (remainder n x))) ; alternatively: (= (remainder n x) 0)
```

Now we can check if a number is divisible by, say, `3` like this:

```
(divisible? 42 3)
=> #t
```